# Move textview up depending on predictive text

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to change the scale or position of a textview depending on whether the user has predictive text on? I would like my textview to scale vertically up when the user has it on and down with disabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several notification you can subscribe to in order to get keyboard size information:

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```

Use the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` keys in the notification's userInfo dictionary to get keyboard size information. I have not verified, but this size should include the predictive text area of the keyboard.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to go. I have tried that before